# Link doesn't work on Mac OS X 10.6.7

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser, links

I recently got a Mac OS X 10.6.7 and I'm trying to install blender on it, but when I try to press the 'MacOS, Linux, and other versions' it doesn't do anything.

[image]

Blender downloads:

https://www.blender.org/download/

I believe it might have something to do with my issues with updating my device, so here's a link to a question I asked about it.

[Mac OS X 10.6.7 freezes on restart](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334474/mac-os-x-10-6-7-freezes-on-restart)

**Update:** The screenshot was taken on a windows computer, but when I check the website the download info still says windows instead of macOS.

Comment: I decided that since the link works on my windows computer, I could try get the macOS blender on it and then transfer it to the mac, but I am unsure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct link from the site if you want to try. I don't know of a reason why it would prompt you to download the Windows version if you visit the original link above on a Mac browser.

[Direct Blender for Mac Link](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-macOS-10.6.dmg/)

Comment: It turns out that safari had issues, so all I had to do was download google.

Comment: @Angyeet google is an search engine you cannot download it, Also only accept answers if they answer your question - by your comment it does not

Comment: i assume the OP meant he downloaded Google Chome.

Answer (score 0):

if you're downloading on a mac, then the download blender info will be for the Mac version. It looks like you're on a PC. Try downloading on a mac directly.

[image]

Comment: I took the screenshot on my windows laptop, but when I go to download it on my mac, the download info still says Windows. Do I still try and download that one?